# What does [Item]やったらなんでも売ってる mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, kansai-ben

So Link (this elf kid) walks into an weapons shop and the seller/vendor says:

武器やったらなんでも売ってるで、金塊次第やなあ！

I guess he's saying:

If you want to buy weapons, I sell everything, provided you have the money! Muhaha!

やったら 1. if that's the case​
なんでも売ってる I sell everything

But this translation is a bit off, doesn't sound smooth.

Answer (score 2):

> 「武器{ぶき}やったらなんでも売{う}ってるで、金塊次第{きんかいしだい}やなあ！」

This is Kansai speech.

やったら ＝ だったら ≒ なら

売ってるで ＝ 売ってるよ

やなあ ＝ だなあ

Highly literal TL:

> "If it's about weapons, I sell everything; It (what you can get) would all depend on the gold nuggets (that you have)."

More naturally:

> "When it comes to weapons, I've got it all.  Money will talk."

Comment: @ l'électeur That's perfect! I once received a spot on, accurate translation for this question from an email response someone sent me over a decade ago, but I lost the darn message years ago. I only wrote the translation based off what little memory I might have left, but I still had a feeling it was a little off. Thanks a million!